# UIWebView LoadData is not accepting Nil values for textEncodingName and baseURL

Tags: ios, uiwebview, swift2

Till Swift 1.2 version, UIWebView LoadData was accepting nil values, but Swift 2.0 is throwing error "Swift does not conform to protocol NilLateralConvertible".

Swift 1.2: Works fine

```
self.webView.loadData(tempData!, MIMEType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName: nil, baseURL: nil)
```

Swift 2.0: Throws error

```
self.webView.loadData(tempData!, MIMEType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName: nil, baseURL: nil)
```

Comment: Any leads? Get warnings when using Swift 3+ with "NSURL() as URL"

Answer (score 15):

This works for me:

```
webView.loadData(pdfDownload, MIMEType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName: "", baseURL: NSURL())
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3:

```
self.webView.loadData(tempData!, MIMEType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: NSURL() as URL)
```

Comment: This does compile, but it will crash at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

The default character encoding is `UTF-8` so you can do in this way:

> self.webView.loadData(tempData!, MIMEType: "application/pdf",
>   textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: NSURL())

Answer (score 1):

Apple has updated the declarations and they now require non-nil values. They have adding reality to the declarations for the benefit of Swift (and ObjC).

```
- (void)loadData:(NSData   * nonnull)data
        MIMEType:(NSString * nonnull)MIMEType
textEncodingName:(NSString * nonnull)encodingName
         baseURL:(NSURL    * nonnull)baseURL
```

Comment: So, what are we supposed to provide for a baseURL when we don't care?