# How to display a PDF without a base URL in a UIWebView in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, uiwebview, swift3

**I want to display a PDF file in a `UIWebView`.** I already have it as a `Data` object so I don't need to (and cannot) provide a `baseURL`.

#### In Objective-C ...

... the corresponding method was defined as follows:

```
- (void)loadData:(NSData *)data 
        MIMEType:(NSString *)MIMEType 
textEncodingName:(NSString *)textEncodingName 
         baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL;
```

so I could simply pass `nil` as `baseURL` as documented in [Apple's Text Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/DisplayWebContent/DisplayWebContent.html).

#### In Swift 2.0 ...

... the `baseURL` parameter is not optional in the `load(...)` function (why?) so I *had to* pass a valid `NSURL` object. Fortunately, there was an easy workaround described in another [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32967277/2062785): I simply created an empty `NSURL` object.

```
private func showPdf(data: NSData) {
    webView.loadData(data, 
           MIMEType: "application/pdf", 
   textEncodingName: "utf-8", 
            baseURL: NSURL())
}
```

#### Now in Swift 3.0 ...

... the method signature has changed and the `baseURL` parameter has to be a Swift `URL` instead of `NSURL`:

```
open func load(_ data: Data, 
    mimeType MIMEType: String, 
     textEncodingName: String, 
              baseURL: URL)
```

This breaks the workaround because for `URL` there is no empty initializer and creating a `URL` from an empty string is not possible as stated in the Swift documentation:

```
/// Returns `nil` if a `URL` cannot be formed with the string 
/// (for example, if the string contains characters that are illegal 
/// in a URL, or is an empty string).
public init?(string: String)
```

So the question is:
**How can I load a PDF (or any other web content) without providing a `baseURL` inside a `UIWebView` in Swift 3?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually if you have data it came through a URL to start with, so just use that URL.

Or I suppose **you could use the file URL of anything inside your app bundle as the base URL**.

Or maybe you can form the URL as an NSURL and cast to URL with `as`.

Or save the data to disk and call `loadRequest` instead.

Comment: I've tried using different URLs inside the app bundle but I keep getting an empty black screen. That's why I thought the `baseURL` might have something to do with it but if it's only for internal links as you say it shouldn't have any influence on the display of the PDF. Probably something else went wrong during my Swift 3 migration and there's something wrong with my data object. I will need to check that first. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I have not had any trouble with loading using data. But usually data arrives from somewhere, e.g. the net. So it arrived using a URL. So I usually use _that_ URL as the base URL. Did you try that?

Comment: Given the architecture of this particular app it's rather difficult to obtain the original URL where in was downloaded from at the place where the PDF is loaded from data stored on the device.

Comment: But it turned out that as a matter of fact there *was* something wrong with the data object: As in Swift 3 all Core Graphics functions have been updated to Swift style syntax it's now required to call `closePDF()` on the `CGContext` or otherwise the data won't be written to the context destination. This `closePDF()` call was missing when the data object was created.

Comment: That's so interesting that you might want to give it as an answer, even though it isn't what you asked. You never know, it might help someone!

Comment: Done. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, **matt's answer is correct**. It seems like you can use pretty much any URL as `baseURL` because the webview only uses it for internal links in HTML files, for example. If you're loading a PDF instead that doesn't include any internal links the parameter is simply ignored. You can pass `URL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")!` as the `baseURL` and it will still work. I don't really understand why Apple hasn't made the `baseURL` optional then in the first place but it's the way it is.

Secondly, the reason why my `UIWebView` didn't load the PDF was not related to the `baseURL` as I thought when I asked this question. It turned out that the `data` object that I tried to load in the webview was not properly created.

---

#### The Problem:

**Prior to Swift 3** it was possible to write data to the context destination like this:

```
let mutableData = CFDataCreateMutable(nil, 0)

let dataConsumer = CGDataConsumerCreateWithCFData(mutableData)
let pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreate(dataConsumer, &pageRect, nil)

if CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(document) > 0 {
    CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContext, nil)
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(pdfContext, page)
    CGPDFContextEndPage(pdfContext)
}
```

At this point the `mutableData` object had already been written to and contained the PDF page data. Translated to the **new Swift 3 syntax** this reads:

```
let mutableData = CFDataCreateMutable(nil, 0)

let dataConsumer = CGDataConsumer(data: mutableData!)
let pdfContext = CGContext(consumer: dataConsumer!, mediaBox: &pageRect!, nil)

if (document?.numberOfPages)! > 0 {
    pdfContext?.beginPDFPage(nil)
    pdfContext?.drawPDFPage(page!)
    pdfContext?.endPDFPage()
}
```

But calling `endPDFPage()` on the `pdfContext` (or its equivalent `CGPDFContextEndPage()`) **no longer writes any data to the destination**.

---

#### The Solution:

You need to call

```
pdfContext?.closePDF()
```

and that will eventually write the PDF data to your context destination.

After that you can simply load the PDF data inside the webview as described in my question - no matter what `baseURL` you provide.